# How to remove prefix from EF Core owned type column names

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have an entity like this

```
public sealed class Company
{
    public CompanyMainDetails MainDetails { get; private set; }
}
```

Where `CompanyMainDetails`

```
public sealed class CompanyMainDetails
{  
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

And this EF Core configuration:

```
builder
    .OwnsOne(company => company.MainDetails);
```

By default, the column name in `Companies` table is generated as `MainDetails_Name`, but I would like it to just be `Name` so I tried changing the config to

```
builder.OwnsOne(
    company => company.MainDetails,
    config => 
    {
        config
            .Property(mainDetail => mainDetail.Name)
            .HasColumnName("Name");
    });
```

But now the column is generated as `Company_Name`

Is there a way to achieve what I need?

Comment: You could always ditch EF and write the O/RM yourself ^_^ I'm not even joking. You'll have more granular control over your database and data access layer. I'm not sure how to address the issue you've mentioned in EF, but that type of thing, along with many other issues, is what led me to ditching EF in the past.

Comment: Are you sure? Because recently I have tested it and it will use the exact name that you provide.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the owned table column name worked for me.
But I do not use sql schema gerneration, just the runtime entity mapping.

```
        tblEntityReg.OwnsOne(o => o.MyNestedObject, dt =>
        {
            dt.Property(p => p.NestedObjectProp).HasColumnName(nameof(MyNestedObjectType.NestedObjectProp));               
        });
```

This removes "MyNestedObject_" prefix in db column name.

I verfied it with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer version 6.0.9.

Answer (score 0):

Think about your structure.
You could change the definition to a traditional one to many relationship

```
public sealed class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public CompanyMainDetails MainDetails { get; private set; }
}

public sealed class CompanyMainDetails
{  
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

That way the columns on the CompanyMainDetails table keep the same name.